# Access ClassList property of JSX Elements

Tags: reactjs, reference, react-hooks, element

I have the following problem: I want to have a kind a like 'password status bar' that tells the user which
conditions the password has already fulfilled and which it has to fulfill, but when I try to access the classList of my labels I get the error 'Cannot read property add of undefined' and when I try to console.log the classlist I also get undefined. I am using refs in the labels, so I can access the attributes. I also tried to make it with a state variable, but when I try to read out the refs I always get null. First I tried to only make that component in a method in another component that returns the label, but there I also get undefined every time.

(password and password1 are the inputs from another component (its a password for resetting your password, so you have to confirm the new password) and for testing purposes, I set the pass and pass1 which should be password and password1 to an easy string))

(I am also using react-bootstrap for styling (if it is relevant))
I want to know how to access the classList property of react elements and please explain to me what mistakes I made.

Code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Input, Form, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function PasswordStatus ({password}, {password1}) {

    // const [output, setOutput] = useState('');
    const names = [`[A-Z]`, `[a-z]`, `[0-9]`, `>10 & <26`, `Special`, `Ident`];
    const regexes = [/[A-Z]/g, /[a-z]/g, /[0-9]/g, /^{10, 26}$/, /[ !@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/];
    const refNames = [];
    const pass='Hello';
    const pass1='Hello2';


    for(let i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
        refNames[i] = React.createRef();
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // setOutput(names.map((item, index) => {
        //     return <label className='d-inline' ref={refNames[index]}>{`${item}\u00A0\u00A0`}</label>
        // }));
        for(let j=0; j<names.length; j++) {
            console.log(refNames[j]);
            if(pass.match(regexes[j]) ===null || pass1.match(regexes[j])===null) refNames[j].classList.add('text-danger');
            else refNames[j].classList.add('text-success');
         }
    }, []);

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     console.log(refNames);
        
    //     console.log(refNames[0]);
    //     let i = refNames[0];
    //     console.log(i.classList);
    //     console.log(output);
        // for(let j=0; j<names.length; j++) {
        //     console.log(refNames[j]);
        //     if(pass.match(regexes[j]) ===null || pass1.match(regexes[j])===null) refNames[j].classList.add('text-danger');
        //     else refNames[j].classList.add('text-success');
        //  }
    // }, [output]);


    return(
    <>
   {names.map((item, index) => {
       return <label className='d-inline' ref={refNames[index]}>{`${item}\u00A0\u00A0`}</label>
     })}
   {/* {output} */}
  </>
   );
}

export default PasswordStatus;
```

Comment: Rather than fix this, may I suggest that you scrap the idea of using refs and `classList` and instead take a more React approach?  You want to do that check on each keyUp, so run a function that responds to that event and just calculate your list of classes each time rather than trying to add and subtract from the `classList`.

Comment: Okay, thank you. How can I implement this and how would it look in the right way? And how can I access the values ​​of several elements when I write a function (e.g. click on a button that should query the values ​​from the input fields and, depending on the values, then output an error message or process the data further). I don't really know how this should work without refs (I'm new to react), because you can't access the elements and their values ​​without refs (at least I don't know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the classList property on ObjectRef, not on the actual element.
RefObject has a current property where this item is located.

```
for(let j=0; j<names.length; j++) {
  if(pass.match(regexes[j]) ===null || pass1.match(regexes[j])===null) refNames[j].current.classList.add('text-danger');
  else refNames[j].current.classList.add('text-success');
}
```

Comment: But how can I then add the classes to this element?

Comment: As in the example above. You're still using classList.add() but on the `current` property instead of on the ref.
https://codesandbox.io/s/new-frog-c845y

Comment: Im so stupid sorry. Thank you for your help :D